# Why are my double quotes are missing in the output?

Tags: perl

I tried to convert strings from lower case to upper case. While I achieved that, I found my double quotes were removed from the output. I want to be clear why the substitution fails here.

#### Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @ar = <DATA>;
my $str = join '', @ar;

#print $str;

if ( $str =~ s/\"([^"]*)\"/uc($1)/eg ) {
    print $str;
}
__DATA__
output = "    as  (10) print "it if achieved. print" # This is comment.NUMBERS"
```

Obtained output:

```
output =     AS  (10) PRINT it if achieved. print # THIS IS COMMENT.NUMBERS
```

Expected output:

```
output = "    AS  (10) PRINT "it if achieved. print" # THIS IS COMMENT.NUMBERS"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s/\"([^"]*)\"/uc($1)/eg` - `$1` represents match **inside** brackets `()`. You have include double quotes in match to be replaced but **outside** brackets.

Possible fix:
`s/(\"[^"]*\")/uc($1)/eg`

Answer (score 6):

The quotes are all disappearing because they're outside the capture in your regex.  Changing it to `s/("[^"]*")/uc($1)/eg` gets us your desired output:

```
output = "    AS  (10) PRINT "it if achieved. print" # THIS IS COMMENT.NUMBERS"
```

Note that the inner section isn't mapped to all caps.  This is a hint to how the regex is actually matching things in your string - it finds two matches: `"    as  (10) print "` and `" # This is comment.NUMBERS"`.  The text inside the inner quotes isn't matched by the regex at all.  This is important, because it means that this solution is fragile and *it will break* on data which doesn't contain two nested sets of quotes and you want to capitalize only the text which is inside the outer quotes, but outside the inner quotes.

Comment: it may break also if there is some escaping character like `\"`

Comment: following regex may handle backslash escaping better `s/"(?:\\.|[^"])*"/uc($&)/eg` note that using `$&` instead of `$1` allows not using brakets arround match